# What are these connectors?

Tags: connector, identification

In the top-right of this panel, you can see two red and two white connectors. Can anyone help me identify what kind of Molex they are?

[image: Device with connectors]

**Edit**: Here is what the cable end of the connector looks like, ignore the extra piece of wire shorting some of the connections:

[image]

Comment: Could we possibly get a close up? Along with a ruler for dimensions?

Comment: This is a picture I found online. I do however have one of these at home so I can snap a pic later on.

Comment: These look incredibly similar to the DC backup supply connectors used on certain Cisco networking gear. They're likely a standard type, but I don't know specifically.

Comment: Are you sure they're made by Molex? Do you have a manufacurer's part number for the assembly?

Comment: My guess would be the common post headers made by 3M, Amphenol, and many others.  The most common size has 0.025" square pins on 0.1" centers, but there are also metric versions.  They may be called "ribbon cable connectors".

Comment: Is this some kind of Konami dev unit? It looks cool.

Comment: It's a System 573, used in a lot of older Konami arcade games.

Comment: @raaymaan I don't think they are by Molex, I just wrote that to try and make it clearer that I was talking about the connectors themselves, rather than what they are actually for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out, they are JST XMR connectors.

Specifically XMR-10V and XMR-06V